# can we set more than one port in postgresql.config file?

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to remote connect MsSQL from PostgreSQL using Pg-admin, but every time i try to connect using dblink_connect function, im not able to connect and the Pg-admin throw the error :

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
SQL state: 08001
```

The things I have tried:

specify the port number in the connection string in db_link which is 8583 
  but it still throw the error as below

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
SQL state: 08001
```

changing the port in postgresql.conf file from 5432 to 8583 and restart, but it still throws error as below

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
SQL state: 08001
```

So, can I have more than one port number in the `postgresql.conf` file where hoping it will work that way.

Comment: So the connection only fails through dblink but connecting to the same host and port through `psql`, pgAdmin or any other SQL client does work?

Comment: yes,correct @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server from PostgreSQL using `dblink`, that is only for connecting to remote PostgreSQL databases.

You should use [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) and define foreign tables in PostgreSQL, but that works only for reading data.

If you need to write to the Microsoft SQL Server database, you have few options:

- You could write to the Microsoft SQL Server database from your client code rather than from the PostgreSQL database; that is probably the most viable solution.
- You could write a PL/Python or PL/Perl stored procedure and write to the remote database from there.

Comment: this is the only choice to connect Microsoft SQL from PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes. But it is a very good choice (unless you need to write to the remote database, in which case you are lost).

Comment: okay, thanks for the sharing. anyway it will be great also if you can share any reference on how to write to remote database. thanks.

Comment: You could extend tds_fdw to support writing, but be warned that that is non-trivial. You could write to the Microsoft SQL Server database from your client code rather than from the PostgreSQL database; that is probably the most viable solution. You could write a PL/Python or PL/Perl stored procedure and write to the remote database from there.